# How to determine if the sequence of array values is palindromic?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, sequence

Write a program that will take 10 integers and store them in an array. The program should test if the sequence of numbers is palindromic. This means that it read the same forwards as it does backwards. Here are two examples:

**Please type 10 integers:** `[1|2|3|7|7|7|7|3|2|1]`

**The sequence is palindromic.**

**Please type 10 integers:** `[1|2|3|7|7|7|7|2|3|1]`

**The sequence is not palindromic.**

And my code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class problem4 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type 10 integers:");
        int[] num = new int[10];
        int[] reverse = new int[10];
        for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
            num[a] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        int b = 0;
        int c = 9;
        while (c != 0) {
            reverse[c] = num[b];
            c--;
            b++;
            if (c == 0) break;
        }
        if (num[0] == reverse[9] && num[1] == reverse[8] && num[2] == reverse[7] && num[3] == reverse[6] && num[4] == reverse[5])
            System.out.println("The sequence is palindromic.");
        else 
            System.out.println("The sequence is not palindromic.");
    }
}
```

No build messages however, it always says that the sequence is palindromic regardless of what I input.

Comment: Why not just take the values, put them in *one* array, and iterate it from both ends making sure the front and end elements are the same along the way?

Comment: If you don't *have* to use arrays you could push the first 5 into a stack then check the next 5 against the values `pop()`-ed off the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the reversed array and compare the elements with it.

try this in your code :

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please type 10 integers:");
   int[] num = new int[10];
   int[] reverse = new int[10];
   for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
       num[a] = scan.nextInt();
    }

if (num[0] == num[9] && num[1] == num[8] && num[2] == num[7] 
     && num[3] == num[6] && num[4] == num[5])
        System.out.println("The sequence is palindromic.");
 else 
    System.out.println("The sequence is not palindromic.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can  just  create a simple method and pass the array to check for palindrom.

.......main start here

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type 10 integers:");
    int[] num = new int[10];
    int[] reverse = new int[10];
    for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
        num[a] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(palin(num));
```

.......main ends here
and method in the class

you basically divide the array into two 1 2 3 7 7  <----> 7 7 3 2 1

and check if front is the same as back, with first being the starting index and prev being the last index.

```
public static String palin(int[] arr){
    int prev, first;
    boolean tr = true;
    for(first = 0, prev = arr.length-1; first < arr.length/2; prev--,first++){
        if(arr[first] != arr[prev]){
            tr = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return tr ? "Is a palindromic":"Not palindromic";   
 }
```

> all together

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


public class problem4 {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type 10 integers:");
    int[] num = new int[10];
    int[] reverse = new int[10];
    for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
        num[a] = scan.nextInt();
    }

   System.out.println(palin(num));
}   

    public static String palin(int[] arr){
    int prev, first;
    boolean tr = true;
    for(first = 0, prev = arr.length-1; first < arr.length/2; prev--,first++){
        if(arr[first] != arr[prev]){
            tr = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return tr ? "Is a palindromic":"Not palindromic";   
 }

}
```

Comment: FYI: you basically check it twice with `first < arr.length - 1`.

Comment: I am check front and backwards at the same time, first at and 0 and prev start from the end of the array. its the same like using the builtin iterator for previous and next but didnt want that, I want him to understand. @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Yes, but `prev` and `first` cross each other so each element except the first and last are checked twice.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes i got, thanks for the hints, it makes it more fast without repetition. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by iterating one half of the array (if `num[a]` isn't equal to `num[num.length - a - 1]` it isn't a palindrome). Something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please type 10 integers:");
int[] num = new int[10];
for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
    num[a] = scan.nextInt();
}
boolean isPalindrome = true;
for (int a = 0; a <= num.length / 2; a++) {
    if (num[a] != num[num.length - a - 1]) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isPalindrome) {
    System.out.println("The sequence is palindromic.");
} else {
    System.out.println("The sequence is not palindromic.");
}
```

Which I tested (as specified) like

```
Please type 10 integers:
1 2 3 7 7 7 7 3 2 1
The sequence is palindromic.
```

and

```
Please type 10 integers:
1 2 3 7 7 7 7 2 3 1
The sequence is not palindromic.
```